# Divide a size among threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, java-threads

I'm kind of beginner in parallel computing, so by looking to a java code for threading:

```
int threadNum = 2;
in middleSum[threadNum];
int size = 2000;
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
int array[size];
int setThreadSize = size/threadNum;


// this part will be excueted by a thread with different `idThread`
for(i=idThread*setThreadSize;i<(idThread-1)*setThreadSize;i++){
    middleSum[idThread] += array[i];
}

wait(); // waiting function that should wait for all threads



// only first thread (thread 0) will excute this part
if(idThread==0){
    for(i=0;i<threadNum;i++){
        sum += middleSum[i];
    }
}
```

As far as I can see that the array is divided correctly among the threads, but I'm not sure; what do you think?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? And please add all the relevant code.

Comment: It's a more theoretical question, giving this; do you think that the array is divided correctly among the thread or not? @akuzminykh

Comment: I want to help but I'm struggeling to understand your question. If it's about splitting an array of size `N` into parts that are to be processed each by different threads you could do: Every thread processes the part: `N / nThreads * threadIndex` to `N / nThreads * (threadIndex + 1) - 1`. Or something similar.

Comment: Many thanks, but my question is simple; giving above initializations and code; do you think that the array is divided correctly among the threads? if no which line is causing the problem? @akuzminykh